# OnClientClick and AJAX in RadControls for ASP.NET (telerik) not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have the following code:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="rlpMain">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

This code does not fire my code behind event which I have written in a .vb file.

Pls help me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may need to provide a confirmation dialog to the users and initiate an AJAX request if accepted. Confirmation using standard post backs often looks like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
```

The OnClientClick should be changed a bit to work with AJAX:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" />
```

When the button is ajaxified by added the necessary AJAX setting to RadAjaxManager or when the button is placed within RadAjaxPanel control.

Alternatively, the OnRequestStart client-side event could be used to implement more complex logic. Here is a sample script:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnRequestStart(ajaxControl, eventArgs) {
            var eventTarget = eventArgs.get_eventTarget(); 
            if (eventTarget == "<%= ImageButton1.UniqueID %>") {
                return confirm('Are you sure?');
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: After spending a lot of time looking for a solution, This works! great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the RadControls, you can use a RadButton as an ImageButton as defined here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-image-buttons.html

Create a button with the OnClientClicking attribute set to a function that calls a confirm (or radconfirm for sticking within telerik) below:

```
function ConfirmDeletion(sender, args) {
    var ContinuePostBack = Function.createDelegate(sender, function (clickedOK) {
        if (clickedOK) {
            this.click();
        }
    });
    var text = "Are you sure you wish to delete this attribute?";
    radconfirm(text, ContinuePostBack, 300, 100, null, "Deletion");
    args.set_cancel(true);
}
```

This will cancel the postback, but then click the button via the delegate ContinuePostBack if the user clicked OK. I have used this code a lot for prompting deletions.